# How to specify Job executor to only use defined process engines?

Tags: spring-boot, multi-tenant, camunda

I am setting up a Spring boot application with Camunda. I want to use a multi-tenant setup as defined in "https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/multi-tenancy/#one-process-engine-per-tenant"

I have managed to setup multiple process engines via Java (so not with processes.xml, but coded), but there always seems to be a default Process Engine. How do i achieve a setup with only the process engines i defined?

Extra information:

- each process engine uses its own datasource, derived via context

  I want to avoid the default process engine, because it needs its own datasource. I dont want to setup a datasource/database for a process engine without a tenant. (if i don't setup a datasource for the default, there will be errors thrown by the job executor not getting a connection)

The setup I've tried is in the following block, but for some reason there always is a "default" processengine.

```
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Bean
    @Order(4)
    public void multipleCamunda(){
        log.info("Starting Camunda Multitenant");
        this.targetDatasources.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {

            String tenant = (String) entry.getKey();
            DataSource tenantDatasource = (DataSource) entry.getValue();
            SpringProcessEngineConfiguration standaloneProcessEngineConfiguration = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();
            standaloneProcessEngineConfiguration.setDataSource(tenantDatasource);
            standaloneProcessEngineConfiguration.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate("true");
            standaloneProcessEngineConfiguration.setProcessEngineName(tenant);
            DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(fondsDatasource);
            standaloneProcessEngineConfiguration.setTransactionManager(dataSourceTransactionManager);
            standaloneProcessEngineConfiguration.setHistory(HistoryLevel.HISTORY_LEVEL_FULL.getName());
            standaloneProcessEngineConfiguration.setJobExecutorDeploymentAware(true);

            // deploy all processes from folder 'processes'
            Resource[] resources = new Resource[0];
            try {
                resources = resourceLoader.getResources("classpath:/bpm/*.bpmn");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            standaloneProcessEngineConfiguration.setDeploymentResources(resources);

            ProcessEngine processEngine = standaloneProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine();

          RuntimeContainerDelegate.INSTANCE.get().registerProcessEngine(processEngine);

            beanFactory.registerSingleton("processEngine" + tenant,processEngine);


            log.info("Started process Engine for " + tenant);
        });

    }
```

The maven dependencies i use:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-engine-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.javaee</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-ejb-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter- 
 webapp</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I assume that I need to define a @Bean for some kind of ConfigurationBean, but I can't figure out which one and how. Please tell me what configuration bean I need to autowire and how.

** Solution **

In order to stop the default initialization, you need to edit the application.yaml and add

```
camunda:
  bpm:
    enabled: false
```

Setting the same property in a CamdundaBpmProperties somehow doesn't seem to work.

When you have done this, the default startup won't occur and the process engine will start when adding a process engine via the code snippet posted above

Comment: Do you have `@EnableProcessApplication` annotation in your spring boot config? See https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/process-applications/

Comment: Your dependencies look strange ... are you using a JEE application server (like wildfly) or are you running camunda with the spring boot starter? If so, remove the ejb-client and engine-cdi dependencies, you do not need them in spring

Comment: @JanGalinski You are right. i removed them. I am running with the spring boot starter.